# Is it possible to do partial word searches in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Is it possible to do partial word searches in Gmail? For example, if I wanted to search for an email from Johndoe@gmail.com can I search for `ndoe`?

Answer (score 4):

No, as of now it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

At least there's a workaround if you need to find an email where you only remember part of a word to search for. (BTW, this happens often to me.)

Import the set of email messages that you want to search in Mozilla Thunderbird. Install the *ImportExportTools* add-on and use it to export the messages locally to a searchable text format. Now use a tool such as Notepad++ to search. Such programs can easily make partial word searches in collections of files.