# How to find an email containing (a specific part of) a URL?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I am asking what seems to be a simple question, but I can't figure it out.

I have a link that points to https://example.com/someAwesomeEndpoint. In the email it's written as: "[Click here](https://example.com/someAwesomeEndpoint)".

I want to find the email and find it on `/someAwesomeEndpoint` as I know I only received one email ever with `/someAwesomeEndpoint`.

But I can't seem to do it, nor could I find any operators helping me with this. Is this possible to do via Gmail's search feature or do I have to create some program for it?

**Edit:** this question is not similar to part or wildcard search questions as the fundamental part of this question is: can I find a URL? The "a specific part of" is in parentheses as it is extra information but not necessary information, in other words: a nice to have. If a URL has "Click here" as text but the URL is https://example.com then is there a way to find my email by typing https://example.com ? I haven't find out how to do this.

Specifically the questions it isn't similar to:

- [Gmail filter on partial "words"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85044/gmail-filter-on-partial-words)
- [Wildcard search in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/wildcard-search-in-gmail)
- [Is it possible to do partial word searches in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21619/is-it-possible-to-do-partial-word-searches-in-gmail)

Partial is secondary, fundamental is finding an email by knowing a URL from the email body when that URL is only in the HTML of the mail and not in the plain visible text of the mail.